# I am doing HTTP POST to upload .xlsx file to server using RESTApi , But I am getting error 500 error from server

Tags: angularjs

In swagger API test i can upload the .xlsx file but in angularjs if i upload by formdata . file file format is in

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymhgCEAkC4MYuPPTD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="TID_Input_File_CCD _TO_SWINKPAY.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarymhgCEAkC4MYuPPTD--
```

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` instead of `octate-stream`

Answer (score 0):

Use the option argument of the Blob constructor to set the MIME type:

```
var mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
var xlsBlob = new Blob([blob], {type: mimeType});

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", xlsBlob, "TID_Input_File_CCD _TO_SWINKPAY.xlsx");
```

Comment: angular.js:14516 ReferenceError: blob is not defined
    at dashboardController.uploadfile (super_admin_dashboard.js:107)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), <anonymous>:2:193)
    at e (angular.js:26969)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:18172)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:18272)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26974)
    at hg (angular.js:3734)
    at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:3722)

Comment: new Blob([blob] ... what is the blob value